# How can i fix this error ??????: SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR: Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Tags: sql, talend

Hey everyone i am having some trouble with this query :

UPDATE INP.VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU_ELIE RCU
set

```
     RCU.CIVILITE = WRK.CIVILITE
   , RCU.NOM = WRK.NOM 
   , RCU.PRENOM = WRK.PRENOM
   , RCU.MONTANT = WRK. MONTANT
   , RCU.EMAIL = WRK.EMAIL
   , RCU.DATE_ANNIVERSAIRE = WRK.DATE_ANNIVERSAIRE
   , RCU.CODE_POSTAL = WRK.CODE_POSTAL
   , RCU.VILLE_POSTALE = WRK.VILLE_POSTALE
   , RCU.ADRESSE_POSTALE_1 = WRK.ADRESSE_POSTALE_1
   , RCU.ADRESSE_POSTALE_2 = WRK.ADRESSE_POSTALE_2
   , RCU.ADRESSE_POSTALE_3 = WRK.ADRESSE_POSTALE_3
   , RCU.ADRESSE_POSTALE_4 = WRK.ADRESSE_POSTALE_4
   , RCU.PAYS = WRK.PAYS
   , RCU.CODE_LANGUE_ISO = WRK.CODE_LANGUE_ISO
   , RCU.TYPE = WRK.TYPE
   , RCU.SECTEUR = WRK.SECTEUR
   , RCU.SIRET = WRK.SIRET
   , RCU.RAISON_SOCIALE = WRK.RAISON_SOCIALE
   , RCU.CODE_APE = WRK.CODE_APE
   , RCU.KBIS = WRK.KBIS
   , RCU.DATE_KBIS =WRK.DATE_KBIS
   , RCU.STATUT = WRK.STATUT
   , RCU.MAG_PREFERE =WRK.MAG_PREFERE
   , RCU.DATE_PREM = WRK.DATE_PREM
   , RCU.DATE_DER = WRK.DATE_DER
   , RCU.THEME = WRK.THEME
   , RCU.FLAG_CAISSE = WRK.FLAG_CAISSE
   , RCU.DATE_BDR10 = WRK.DATE_BDR10
   , RCU.DATE_BDR30 = WRK.DATE_BDR30
   , RCU.NEWSLETTER = WRK.NEWSLETTER
   , RCU.DATE_CREATION = WRK.DATE_CREATION
   , RCU.DATE_MODIFICATION = WRK.DATE_MODIFICATION
   , RCU.ANNIVERSAIRE = WRK.ANNIVERSAIRE
   , RCU.NOTIFIED = WRK.NOTIFIED
   , RCU.DATE_GOLD = WRK.DATE_GOLD
   , RCU.DATE_GOLD_PLUS = WRK.DATE_GOLD_PLUS
   , RCU.BSMARTPHONE = WRK.BSMARTPHONE
   , RCU.MOBILE = WRK.MOBILE
   , RCU.CREER_PAR = WRK.CREER_PAR
   , RCU.CREATION_SOURCE = WRK.CREATION_SOURCE
   , RCU.MAG_PREMIERE_VENTE = WRK.MAG_PREMIERE_VENTE
   , RCU.FLAG_DATASTAGE = WRK.FLAG_DATASTAGE
   , RCU.LAT = WRK.LAT
   , RCU.LNG = WRK.LNG
   , RCU.CODE_IDENTITE = WRK.CODE_IDENTITE
   , RCU.FIXE = WRK.FIXE
   , RCU.UTILISATEUR ='M1314' 
   , RCU.DATE_MAJ = WRK.DATE_MAJ
```

FROM
(WITH DD_CODE AS (
SELECT code CODE_CLIENT,MAX(DATE_MODIFICATION) MAX_DATE_MODIF
FROM INP.WRK_VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU
GROUP BY CODE)
SELECT W.* FROM INP.WRK_VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU W
INNER JOIN INP.VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU_ELIE R ON W.CODE=R.CODE
WHERE  (W.CODE,W.DATE_MODIFICATION) IN (SELECT CODE_CLIENT,MAX_DATE_MODIF FROM DD_CODE)

) WRK
WHERE
WRK.CODE=RCU.CODE

But as you can see in the title it gives me this error: Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows.

How can i fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please improve formatting to make question more readable, tried to do it for you but it will not let me save it as there is too little text.

Answer (score -1):

The real problem is here

FROM

(WITH DD_CODE AS (
SELECT code CODE_CLIENT,MAX(DATE_MODIFICATION) MAX_DATE_MODIF
FROM INP.WRK_VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU
GROUP BY CODE)

SELECT W.* FROM INP.WRK_VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU W

INNER JOIN INP.VIP_CLIENT_FIDELITE_RCU_ELIE R ON W.CODE=R.CODE

WHERE  (W.CODE,W.DATE_MODIFICATION) IN (SELECT CODE_CLIENT,MAX_DATE_MODIF FROM DD_CODE)

) WRK
WHERE

```
   WRK.CODE=RCU.CODE
```